# Displaying the decision tree in Spark MLlib with the correct feature names

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, decision-tree

I build a decision tree in Spark MLLib

```
val dt = new DecisionTreeClassifier().setLabelCol("indexedLabel").setFeaturesCol("indexedFeatures").setImpurity(impurity).setMaxBins(maxBins).setMaxDepth(maxDepth)
```

I displayed it like this:

```
    val treeModel = model.stages(1).asInstanceOf[DecisionTreeClassificationModel]
println("Learned classification tree model:\n" + treeModel.toDebugString)
```

The result is a textual description of the tree with "Features X"s instead of the actual feature names of my dataset, rendering the tree non-interpretable.

Anyone got pointers to display the tree with the correct feature names rendering the interpretability of the tree possible? Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spark ML(lib) decision tree models (as of the 1.6.X version) do not contain feature specifications. Basically, your feature column ("indexedFeatures") is a double array, where individual array elements function as continuous split threshold values.

There is some feature specification information available in the associated `DataFrame` object. First, check out the metadata of the "indexedFeatures" column. If that's not enough, check out the metadata of its constituent columns, etc.

The [JPMML-SparkML](https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-sparkml) library can be used to export Spark ML pipeline models in PMML data format. Its engine performs some nifty feature specification collection and (re-)construction work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, do you know how you can examine the constituent columns of indexedFeatures?

Comment: If the feature vector was assembled using `VectorAssembler`, then you can get the names of constituent columns via `VectorAssembler#getInputCols()`.